# Can't find id by a given user name

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am trying to get the user id from the user's table called `userDataTbl`(in my MySQL database) by a user name. However, when I run the code below it keeps returning -1 and the result parameter keeps being -1 as if it didn't find the user.

I have also used the method below in order to check if a username already exists in the table-and then I just checked if the result is greater than 0 to return that it exists and otherwise that it doesn't exists, but it didn't work there either and the result kept being -1 even though I put names that did exist in the table. I have tried debugging but it didn't tell me much because it doesn't really show me what the computer does in the query so that I'll know what's wrong with it.
this is the code :

```
//returns a user id according to a name
public int theId(string name)
{
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("Select userId from dbo.userDataTbl where userName=@username", this.connection);
    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", name);
    int result = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result > 0)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command2.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read(); // we have only 1 row
        try
        {
            string foundId = String.Format("{0}", reader["userId"]);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(foundId);
            return id;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I will be very grateful for any help, it's really important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

If you want to get the number of rows affected by the `SELECT` command and save it to an int variable you can use [`Count`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) and [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
"SELECT COUNT(userId)..."
var result = (int)command2.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `int result = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();` line causes problem for you remove that line, change the code as below and run it

```
public int theId(string name)
{
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("Select userId from dbo.userDataTbl where userName=@username", this.connection);
    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", name);
    this.connection.open();
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command2.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.HasRows)
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                string foundId = String.Format("{0}", reader["userId"]);
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(foundId);
                return id; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }                
}
```

Hope this helps you - Happy coding !!